# iOS: Get API MISUSE: Cancelling connection for unused peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I have a singleton class holding a `CBPeripheral` array. When a new device is discovered, it is added to that array. This array is used as a `UITableView` data source. When a table view cell is selected by the user, a connected is made to the selected `CBPeripheral` via fetch.

Unfortunately I get this error:

> [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: Cancelling connection for unused peripheral `<CBPeripheral: 0x1c0103e70, identifier = xxx, name = xxx, state = connecting>`, Did you forget to keep a reference to it?

I searched stack overflow, there have been similar questions asked before, but all of them say the root cause is "not add peripheral to a strong reference, so iOS free it". But I have added them to an array.

Code:

```
class BLEManager:NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

static let sharedInstance = BLEManager()
var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
var connectedService: BLEDSPService?
var delegate: BLEDiscoveryDelegate?

var readUUIDString: String
var writeUUIDString: String
var serviceUUIDString: String

var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?

var peripherals = [CBPeripheral]() {
    didSet {
        delegate?.peripheralDidDiscoverNewOnes()

    }
}

init(serviceUUIDString: String, readUUIDString: String, writeUUIDString: String) {

    self.readUUIDString = readUUIDString
    self.writeUUIDString = writeUUIDString
    self.serviceUUIDString = serviceUUIDString
    super.init()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main);
}

internal func startScanning() {

    let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: serviceUUIDString)
    let options = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: 0]
    centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID], options: options)

}

func stopScanning() {
    centralManager.stopScan()
    delegate?.peripheralDidStopScan()
}



open func connectTo(index: Int) {    
    if let current = connectedPeripheral {
        disconnectPeripheral(current)
    }
    if index < peripherals.count {
        connectPeripheral(peripherals[index])
        stopScan()
    }
}

 @objc func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    guard let name = peripheral.name?.lowercased() else {
        return
    }
    guard (name.contains(NamesManager.shared.scanName)) else {
        return
    }
    if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
        delegate?.peripheralDidDiscovered()
    }
}
```

But if I save peripheral to a var, then connect it. it works:

```
var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?

open func connectTo(index: Int) {

    if let current = connectedPeripheral {
        connectPeripheral(current)
    }
    stopScan()

}

@objc func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    guard let name = peripheral.name?.lowercased() else {
        return
    }
    guard (name.contains(NamesManager.shared.scanName)) else {
        return
    }

        if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            connectedPeripheral = peripheral
            peripherals.append(peripheral)
            stopScanning()
            delegate?.peripheralDidDiscovered()
        }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant code, including the declaration of your singleton class instance and the conformance to `CBCentralManagerDelegate`.